# auto_increment column for a group of rows?

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I am trying to figure out how to do a table with 3 columns:

```
unique_id, type, version
```

Where unique_id is AUTO_INCREMENT for each record, and version is AUTO_INCREMENT for each type.

The purpose being, when I insert I only have to specify 'type' and the unique_id and version_id are automatically generated. eg:

```
insert type 'a', then values are:  1 , a , 1
insert type 'a', then values are:  2 , a , 2
insert type 'a', then values are:  3 , a , 3
insert type 'b', then values are:  4 , b , 1
insert type 'b', then values are:  5 , b , 2
insert type 'a', then values are:  6 , a , 4
```

Also would it be fair to say that such a setup is not really normalised? That instead it should be two tables?

Comment: that isn't auto increment for version as it doesn't increment on each insert.  you're talking about a trigger that fires a stored proc.  It could be done as a child table in which case the version wouldn't be in this table but the child table.  that still wouldn't have an auto increment on version though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have auto-generated sequences for each type, but you can generate your own.

```
insert into the_table (type, version)
select 'a', 1 + IFNULL(max(version), 0)
  from the_table
  where type = 'a';
```

Comment: Brilliant!! Given `a` is a variable from a given language. You should also return `0` instead of `max(version)` if `where type = 'a'` might not return anything. +1

Answer (score 0):

If the table will have a lot of rows (and depending on what you're trying to do), then it would be best to have separate tables for each version. Then, insert each type into its proper version-table.